# Creating a C++ function that calls other Lua function

Tags: c++, function, lua, swig

I wonder if it's possible to create a C++ function that takes Lua function as argument to call it.

For example in Lua,

```
function sub()
  print('I am sub function')
end

function main()
  callfunc(sub) //C++ function that takes a function variable to call 
end
```

Is it possible to create `callfunc()` function in C++?

I'm using SWIG by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a callback by passing the Lua interpreter state down to the C++ function using the special [`lua_fnptr.i`](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/lua/lua_fnptr.i) header.  The header file also contains further usage information.

```
%module callback

%include <lua_fnptr.i>

%{
void callfunc(SWIGLUA_FN fn) {
    SWIGLUA_FN_GET(fn);
    lua_call(fn.L,0,0);
}
%}

void callfunc(SWIGLUA_FN fn);
```

```lua
local cb = require("callback")
function hello()
    print("Hello World!")
end
cb.callfunc(hello)
```

```
$ lua5.2 test.lua
Hello World!
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. I will give you a bounty.