# Calling a Lua function from C++ causes crash

Tags: c++, lua

I use the following code to call Lua function from C++ but it crashes sometimes.

```
void callLuaFunction(lua_State *L, const char *name)
{
    if (L == nullptr) return;
    lua_getglobal(L, name);
    if (lua_type(L, -1) != LUA_TFUNCTION)
        return;
    if (lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))
        error("%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: I assume you are using SWIG.  Have you looked at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51152666/1944004) to your other question?

Comment: Yes, I did. But the problem is I needed to use it in `CPP` file not `i` file since I needed to use the function with `SWIGLUA_FN fn` argument in a C++ Class. But I didn't know how to write the class in `i` file so I decided to just take the function name as `string` instead.
But regardless of that, this is a different question I would like to know.

Comment: @HenriMenke I tried adding `lua_pop(L, 1);` at the end and it doesn't seem to crash no more. Do you think it's related to the problem I'm having?

Comment: @HenriMenke Please help me Sir.

Comment: Well, your code is not showing anything that could crash, so I don't really know how to help, sorry.

Comment: OKay Thank you Sir.

Comment: @HenriMenke Please take a look at my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208011/how-to-access-variables-of-the-class-that-runs-the-lua-script-from-lua